# How can i get the usage permission of Movie Images for creating Livewallpaper?

Tags: animation, copyright, legal

I am new to designing and had got work for creating a live wallpaper using some animation characters in movies like Rio,Finding Nemo etc. How can use the images of that i find in google for this purpose.And also what kind of copyright permission i need to get ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your client will have to negotiate rights with the copyright owners.

I would recommend not putting a lot of time into this project until the client is able to provide you with evidence that they're cleared this very important legal hurdle. The "fair use" doctrine is not going to apply to a product that's going to be sold, or in all likelihood, even made available as a free download (especially if it's ad-supported).

You should also consult a lawyer in your area to determine what your personal legal liability might be before you go ahead with this, in case it turned out your client didn't have the right to copy.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed explanation. May i know is there any procedure to contact the copy right holders for this purpose. Because the company i work is okay to contact them for the usage permission and they are planing to create many products based on this pattern both as free(ad-supported) as well as paid .Or is there any common place where we can find them and submit a request for usage permission .

Comment: Generally, one digs into the corporate website to find the legal or rights department contact info.